# UIApplication openURL - get rid of %0A

Tags: ios, rss, uiapplication, openurl, linefeed

**Issue:**

I'm parsing some info from an xml file (RSS feed) into a feed reader I'm developing. When trying opening news URL with Safari `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]` is not working.

I suspect the xml file itself is not well prepared. Actually, I'm struck on this and I just can't figure a way out.

**Details:**

The project works fine with all feeds it was tested with, only a particolar feed is not working. To be more specific, when parsed it gives this kind of url: `%0Ahttp://google.com%0A`

[Here](http://www.ivys.it/uploads/rss_basket.xml) is the XML file I'm trying to read.

I'm using [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)'s RSS reader tutorial as a workbench.

This is the code I'm using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry.articleUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

Getting this: `2013-03-22 12:25:57.918 myApp[426:c07] Failed to open url:%0Ahttp://google.it/index.html%0A`

Please note: every single feed I tested this project with (say 20+) didn't give any trouble. Any help will have my personal blessing for a healthy and prosperous life.

Comment: Hint: %0A is a line feed.

Comment: `%OA` is the encoding for a line feed character.

Comment: Ok, that was already a statement. See tags ;-) Give something more consistent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with XML parsing, this is about correct URL.

`[NSURL URLWithString:[entry.articleUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`
This is very, very wrong.

You should never escape the whole URL. You should escape only the query parameters. The `%0A` in the beginning and in the end is caused by encoding a line break.

In this case, they should be already escaped, so just trim the white spaces:

```
NSString* urlString = [entry articleUrl];
NSString* trimmedUrlString = [urlString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:trimmedUrlString];
```

Comment: I just love you. I was forgetting about line breaks. I do suppose those line breaks come from here: `<link>
http://google.it/index.html
</link>`.
A way to escape url in pieces would have been cuttin' it out using `[url host]` and adding escaped `http://` and `[url pathComponents]` I guess. But such a path is very tricky to follow... What do you think?

(many thanks again, my very blessing o'er you)

Comment: @DaemonPainter Why would you like to encode the URL again? The encoding is part of the URL creation. If you get an URL, it's either already encoded or invalid.